# Extend and enumeration constant

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible to have one enumeration constant extend another one (from the same enumeration)?

**Pseudo-code:**

```
private enum Mode{
  FRIGHTENED, BLINKING extends FRIGHTENED, SCATTER
}
```

This way, one could use the enum-constants in a `switch`-block like this:

```
switch (some_mode){
  case FRIGHTENED:
    // This would trigger when the actual "some_mode" is set
    //  to FRIGHTENED or BLINKING
    break;
  case BLINKING:
    // This would only trigger if the actual "some_mode" is set to BLINKING
}
```

Is there any pattern which would allow me to do this, or am I just completely out of my mind?

---

I might have to be a little more clear about the shown use-case in a `switch`-statement: I plan to not check for all possible values, but only for the "parent" one.

```
if (some_mode == Mode.FRIGHTENED){
  // The behavior in FRIGHTENED and BLINKING mode is the same. The only
  //  difference is the way they are visualized.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tortured way to simulated this, but no, it's not possible for one enumeration constant to extend another.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, enums can't be extended, so if you want to collate strongly-related enums, you can use **nested enum** constructs. View [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4718959/544983) please.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there's no way to do that.  The closest alternative is

```
switch (some_mode){
  case BLINKING:
    // This would only trigger if the actual "some_mode" is set to BLINKING
    // no break statement!
  case FRIGHTENED:
    // This would trigger when the actual "some_mode" is set
    //  to FRIGHTENED or BLINKING
}
```